# How to fix python scrapy errors related to poolmanager https connection to get raw data from a web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I'm using the sracpy library for the first time to scrape a website using selenium. I don't get any error using the request lib but I get errors, given in the code snipet block below, using urllib3 with beautifulsoup, the aim is to get raw data instead of HTML script containing first 200 chars. To understand my point, please refere to the code pasted for you. Thank you.

I tried requests lib in Python with scrapy to extract data from a target website. It's working fine but next I'm intended to carry out the similir job using urllib3 & beautifulsoup to extract raw data instead of HTML script of the first 200 chars. I hope it make sense, if not, please ask me. Looking forward.

```
import requests
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Extracting web data using requests urllib3 & BeautifulSoap

print "Retrieved the following data (Raw Form) using 'urllib3' lib \n"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'https://authoraditiagarwal.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data, 'lxml')
print soup.title
print soup.title.text
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='authoraditiagarwal.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: 
Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Comment: problem is SSL (`https`), not `PoolManager`. As I remeber other modules also had problem with SSL. In `requests` you can turn off this problem using `requests.get( ..., verify=False)`

Comment: Thank you for the comment but the error comes from the following module. The requests.get is working fine. I'm trying the other way round using urllib3.

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'https://authoraditiagarwal.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data, 'lxml')
print (soup.title)
print (soup.title.text)

Comment: you have in message `SSLError` and `certificate verify failed` so it has problem with SSL (`https`). Currently `requests.get()` can work correctly because it could resolved this problem.

Comment: I run your code on Python 3.7 and it works without problem. On Python 2.7 it works too but it shows warning "InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings"

Comment: I'm running Python 2.7 for the given module. May be there's something else wrong in my code which I'll look at that. Thank you for you input. Much appreciated. Looking to your help in future too.